# Как сделать чтоб слайдер работал без перерыва

Tags: javascript

У меня есть вот такой скрипт:

```
<script>
var num=new Array(4);
for(var i=1;i<4;i++)
{
    num[i]=new Image();
    num[i].src="img"+i+".jpg";
}

function slider(count)
{
    document.images[0].src="img"+count+".jpg";
    count--;
    if(count>=1)
    {
        setTimeout("slider("+count+");", 3000);
    }
}
</script>
```

И вот такой простой html код:

```
<img src="img4.jpg" width="595" height="263" onLoad="slider(4)">
```

Как сделать так, чтоб фотографии прокручивались снова и снова без всяких кликов и обновлений?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

сделать что-то вроде этого:

***count = count || 4;***

if(count>=1)
{
    setTimeout("slider("+count+");", 3000);
}

т.е. если счетчик закончится - он вернется к четырем и заново пойдет цикл, иначе все будет, как обычно. Решение корявое, но так меньше всего редактировать код придется

Answer (score 0):

```
var i = 4;

var banner = new Array(i);

banner[0] = '1 Banner';
banner[1] = '2 Banner';
banner[2] = '3 Banner';
banner[3] = '4 Banner';

setInterval(function()
{
    i--;

    document.body.innerHTML = banner[i];

    if(i == 0)
    {
        i = banner.length;
    }

}, 1500);
```

Comment: чуток эстетики

    var banner = [];
    
    banner.push('1 Banner');
    // ...
    banner.push('N Banner');
    var i = banner.length;

    // и далее по тексту, setInterval(...)